# POST $_SESSION variable using HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, post

hope you are all doing well. I'm not too sure on how I worded the title so I'm sorry for that.

I have this code:

```
<form method="POST" action="checkoutManager.php" name="submitOrder">
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
$item_total = 0;

$total;

foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) {
    $item_total += (($item["price"]-$item["discount"])*$item["quantity"]);

    $total = $total + $item_total;

?>

<tr>
<td class="product-name">
    <?php echo $item["name"]; ?> <strong class="product-qty"> × <?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?></strong>
</td>

<td class="product-total">
    <span class="amount"><?php echo "$".$item_total; ?></span>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
$item_total = 0;

    }
}
?>


<input type="submit" name="btnSubmitOrder" value="Submit Order">
</form>
```

How would I go about submitting all the $_SESSION items in using form tag. I have tried submitting as an array but failed. All help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your form is not submitting any cart_item

Comment: Pass all your items like <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $item["price"]; ?>"> in form

Comment: it must be like name="price[]"

Answer (score 2):

why don't you create hidden elements like

```
<input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
```

and anything you need use hidden input field and you can access them after the submit button is clicked by using `$_POST` in your **checkoutManager.php**

**UPDATE**

simply you can process all the fields in **checkoutManager.php** using session, you dont need any form to be submitted. create a link to **checkoutManager.php** and do all the calculations there

Comment: But I want to be able to submit the $_SESSION things but there are multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. 
In this code I have added one hideen count field.
By using count u can use for loop after submit. 
I display only one input for name but u can add multiple inputs inside for loop of form. 
I also concated $i variables, so all input names are different as name1, name2,... U can use it on submit as $_POST['name'.$i] after submit.

```html
<form method="POST" action="checkoutManager.php" name="submitOrder">
<?php
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo count($_SESSION["cart_item"]); ?>">
$i=0;
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item)
 {
?>
<input type="text" name="input_name<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>" />
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmitOrder" value="Submit Order">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add input fields in `foreach` loop for all your items that are coming in `$_SESSION["cart_item"]`. After submission, you need to use `foreach` again for inserting all your items in your temp table one by one.

Update your code like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="checkoutManager.php" name="submitOrder">
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
    $item_total = 0;
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) {
        $item_total += 
(($item["price"]-$item["discount"])*$item["quantity"]);
        $total = $total + $item_total;
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $item["price"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $item["name"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="discount[]" value="<?php echo 
$item["discount"]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo 
$item["quantity"]; ?>">
<tr>
    <td class="product-name">
        <?php echo $item["name"]; ?> <strong class="product-qty"> × <?php 
echo $item["quantity"]; ?></strong>
    </td>
    <td class="product-total">
        <span class="amount"><?php echo "$".$item_total; ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    $item_total = 0;
        }
    }
    ?>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmitOrder" value="Submit Order">
</form>
```

And you can access all your input fields after submission in the below way.

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $val){
    echo $_POST['name'][$key];
    echo $_POST['price'][$key];
    echo $_POST['discount'][$key];
    echo $_POST['quantity'][$key];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, could you give me an example of the foreach statement I would need in checkoutManager.php

Comment: Yes its the same like you have used here; foreach($_POST['name'] as $name){  echo $name;  }

Comment: But store everything in your temp table when you add in your cart and get all your data from temp table in your cart.

Comment: Whenever you add any item in your cart page from session, first store that item in your temp table. Getting my point?

Comment: Yes. I understand. I am trying to put all these in a database now but that should be easy.

Comment: Yes go ahead. Let me know if any issue comes.

Comment: Mhmhmh how would I go about adding all of the inputs into one foreach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159727/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-user3724476).